# find words where letters ordered by alphabet

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am trying to find words in sentence in which letters are in alphabetic order using assembly. 
For example:

> Hello my name is acxz i am frz asw

Program should return:

> acxz frz asw

I've written some code in emu8086, but it loops infinitely, and i can't find a mistake. Briefly I want to split my sentence, loop over each word and find the offset of each letter in main alphabetic string and then compare it to the next one in order to find if the previous letter goes before the next letter in alphabet string. I am not an assembly profi so i couldn't find out whats wrong. Where is my mistake(s)? Thanks in advance!

```
sseg SEGMENT stack 'stack'
    DB 256 DUP(?)
sseg ENDS
dseg SEGMENT 'data'
        STR1 DB "ENTER YOUR STRING HERE ->$"
        STR2 DB "YOUR STRING IS ->$"
        STR3 DB "WORD IS ->$"
        INSTR1 DB 250 DUP("$")
        INWORD DB 50 DUP("$")
        NEWLINE DB 10,13,"$"
        LENGTH1 DW $-INSTR1
        BEGINNING DW 10 DUP("$")
        ENDING DW 0
        SEPARATORS DB " " 
        ALPHABET DB "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz" 
        ALPH_LENGTH DW 26
        INWORD_LEN DW 0
dseg ENDS
cseg SEGMENT 'code'
    ASSUME cs:cseg,ss:sseg,ds:dseg,es:cseg
Main PROC FAR
    PUSH DS
    XOR AX,AX
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX,dseg

    MOV DS,AX
    MOV ES,AX


    @beginning:
    LEA SI,INSTR1 + 2
    XOR AX,AX
    LEA DX,STR1
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    XOR AX,AX
    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,INSTR1
    INT 21H

    XOR CX,CX
    MOV CL,[INSTR1 + 1]

    LEA DI,INSTR1 + 2
    ADD DI,CX
    XOR AX,AX
    MOV AL,'$'
    STOSB
    LEA DI,INSTR1 + 2

    @skip_separators:
        ;JCXZ @print_result
    @separators_loop:
        LODSB
        PUSH CX
        LEA DI,SEPARATORS
        MOV CX,1
        REPNE SCASB
        POP CX 
    JNE @word_begin
    LOOP @separators_loop

    @word_begin:

        DEC SI
        MOV BEGINNING,SI
    @skip_word:
        LODSB
        PUSH CX
        LEA DI,SEPARATORS
        MOV CX,1
        REPNE SCASB
        POP CX 
    JE @word_end
    LOOP @skip_word

    @word_end:
        DEC SI
        MOV ENDING,SI
        DEC ENDING 
        ;jmp @exit

    @word_check:
        MOV SI,ENDING
        LEA DI,INWORD
        MOV CX,3
        CMP CX,1
        JE @buffer_word
    @buffer_word:
        STD
        LODSB
        CLD
        STOSB
    LOOP @buffer_word
    MOV CX,3
    MOV SI,BEGINNING
    LEA DI,INWORD
    REPE CMPSB

    JNE @set_pointers

    @set_pointers:
        POP CX
        MOV SI,ENDING
        INC SI
        JMP @skip_separators

@checking: 
        ;MOV AX, ENDING
        ;CMP INWORD, AX
        ;JGE word_found
        ;POP CX
        ;CMP CX, DI
        ;JNE do_check
        ;jMP skip 
        MOV CX, BX
        LEA DI, ALPHABET
        LEA SI, INWORD

@do_check:
        LODSB
        PUSH CX                
        MOV CX, ALPH_LENGTH
        REPNE SCASB             
        POP CX
        JNE @not_found
        loop @do_check
@word_found:
        ; code if word found
@not_found:   

    XOR AX,AX
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE
    INT 21H 

    XOR AX,AX
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,INSTR1
    INT 21H     

RET
Main ENDP
cseg ENDS
end Main
```

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger; watch where it loops and see what values the registers hold at that time. You should be able to figure out for yourself *why* it loops infinitely, and from there, the fix will be obvious. I've never used it, but I'm pretty certain that Emu8086 has a debugger built into it.

Comment: Also, why is there all of that commented-out code in there? What is that supposed to be showing us? If that's just random stuff you tested, perhaps you should take it out. If it's supposed to mean something, perhaps you should add a comment or discussion *explaining* the implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Say what?

> "Hello my name is acxz i am frz asw"
>
> Program should return:
>
> "acxz frz asw"

Given what you say the program should do, the output should be:

```
my is acxz i am frz asw
```

---

### A limited list of errors

- The `assume` is wrong with respect to `ES` - you've coupled it to `cseg` while later you'll correctly set it up to the `dseg`.

  ```
  ASSUME cs:cseg,ss:sseg,ds:dseg,es:Dseg
  ```
- If ever your *separators_loop* finishes (`CX`=0), you need to exit from the program in some way.

  ```
  LOOP @separators_loop
  jmp  @exit
  ```
- What the *word_check* part currently does is checking if the the first 3 characters of a word are equal to the reverse of the last 3 characters of the same word. Not only is this **not** what you intended to achieve, you also just ignore the outcome and continue with the *set_pointers* code.

---

### The problem that crashes

```
@set_pointers:
    POP CX
    MOV SI,ENDING
    INC SI
    JMP @skip_separators
```

**There's nothing useful on the stack that you can pop in the `CX` register!**
With an input sentence of 1 or 2 words this `pop cx` will stumble upon the initially pushed values of `AX` and `DS`, but with a sentence that is longer all odds are off about what will happen.

---

### An advice

Stop using the string primitive instructions (and especially `SCASB`) as if your life depended on them. Everywhere you used these, you've overcomplicated matters enormously.

As an example, this is what the whitespace skipping should do:

```
@separators_loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, " "
    loope @separators_loop
    jz @exit
@word_begin:
```

### And now?

To get this working you need to simplify the task first.

1. Get input from the user
2. Extract from this input a single word
3. Echo this word on the screen followed by a space character
4. Repeat steps 2 and 4 until `CX`=0

Then to finish the original task you insert an additional step between 2 and 4 that validates the word. If it does not, you directly go to step 5.

1. Get input from the user
2. Extract from this input a single word
3. Check if alphabetical, if not goto step 5
4. Echo this word on the screen followed by a space character
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 until `CX`=0